# Finding an example if it exists, for a non-contractible and contractible space with special requirement on quotients of their union?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that $A$ is non-contractible, $B$ is contractible and $B$ is not an one-point set.

I would like to find example(s) if one exists, where $(A\cup B)/A$ and $(A\cup B)/B$ are both contractible.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ to be regarded as subspaces of some ambient space in which the union is formed?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated the question with new details.

Comment: Take $A$ to be a punctured disk and $B$ to be the missing puncture.

Comment: @DanPetersen Then $A\cup B= D^{2}$ and $D^{2}/A = S^{2}$.

Comment: No, $A$ would be $D^2$ minus a point, and $D^2/A$ would be the two-point Sierpinski space, which is contractible.

Comment: @DanPetersen Thank you so much for your answer! This definitely answers my question. But, what if $B$ is not one point set?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav It is bad form to receive an answer and then change your question in response only a few minutes later. You should spend more time than this thinking about a question yourself. One can construct many further variants of the example I gave; one may for example consider $B$ a little line segment in a disk.

Comment: The essential problem is you are trying to conclude something homotopical (contractibility) but your hypotheses don't reflect this. You are considering completely arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and taking unions and quotients, but e.g. the formation of the quotient space $X/Z$ is homotopically well-behaved only when the inclusion $Z \hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration. Here is a more reasonable question you could ask. Suppose that $X$ is a CW complex, with subcomplexes $A$ and $B$. If $B$, $X/B$, and $X/A$ are all contractible, must $A$ be contractible?

Comment: The answer is still no, but is more interesting: the best you can say is that $A$ is acyclic.

Comment: @DanPetersen Thank you for the constructive feedback, I will keep it in mind for the future.